Grafana: number of errors in given interval
When my query looks something like this:
sum(request_total{status!="2xx"})

Grafana gives me a table like this:

So, there were five errors within this time range.
But how do I make it calculate that number?
I am trying
sum(increase(request_total{status!="2xx"}[$__range]))

But that just gives me 0 for some reason.
Here it is plotted in 5m intervals orange line is actual counter, green is the "increment":

What am I doing wrong here?
